# StackEgg leaderboard bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackegg

Anime and Manga SE doesn't have logo, causing this:

[image]

Comment: Not repro'd. Could you check whether your network blocks it, perhaps using the browser console?

Comment: quite possible it's blocked.  console shows nothing out of the ordinary, though.

Comment: F5. CTRL+F5. Clear cache and F5.

Comment: it's most certainly blocked. the network i sit on has strange rules in place for what constitutes unacceptable sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That site does have a logo; I don't know why your browser failed to show it. Either way, what you're seeing is a well-known Firefox issue. FF doesn't respect the specified image dimensions when it displays its broken image alternative. I've added a workaround to prevent this from breaking the layout.

Comment: yep, no issues on my home network and using chrome/win7.